# Multiple transaction scopes in single thread?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to open multiple `TransactionScope`s concurrently in a single .NET thread and switch between them? Something along the lines of:

```
var tx1 = new TransactionScope(...);
var tx2 = new TransactionScope(...);

tx1.Use();
// do some database operations on tx1

tx2.Use();
// do some database operations on tx2
tx2.Complete();

tx1.Use();
// do some more database operations on tx1
tx1.Complete();
```

I want to test some concurrency situations in my database, and keeping the concurrent producers on a single thread would allow me to write neater test code:

```
producer1.DoA(); // must run in txA
producer2.DoB(); // must run in txB
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using an alternative approach: `Task` continuation actions in combination with `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled`. Reads like a charm and runs on different threads like the original subjects under test.

Some pseudo code from my test:

```
Task.Factory
  .StartNew(OpenTx1_Insert1_DoNotCompleteTx1)
  .ContinueWith(OpenTx2_Insert2_CompleteTx2)
  .ContinueWith(Assert_SomeStuff)
  .ContinueWith(CompleteTx1);
```

Comment: You might share a chunk of code, and mark your own answer as the accepted answer so that 1) people will know how you solved the problem when they arrive here via search, and 2) the question will not hang about without an accepted answer, and so be viewed by those of us who go in here to answer questions.

Comment: You cannot accept your own answer immediately - doing it now :-) Also added some sample code.